# return makes integer from pointer without a cast when returning a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

Im writing a code for a school project where we are defining a library and I cant get my function to return correctly

I have tried to redefine my code and change int init_book to int *init_book but that only gives me other errors

```
int init_book(struct book *p_book, const char *p_id, const char *p_title, const char * p_author, struct date p_release) {
    p_book = malloc(sizeof(struct book));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p_book->id[i] = p_id[i];
    }
    p_book->title = malloc(strlen(p_title) * sizeof(char));
    p_book->author = malloc(strlen(p_author) * sizeof(char));
    p_book->title = p_title;
    p_book->author = p_author;
    p_book->release_date = p_release;
    return p_book;
}

//a part of my main function that initiates the function

if (init_book(&a1, "000000009", "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", "J. K. Rowling", a1date)) {
        printf("Initialization succeeded\n");
        printf("%s\n", a1.title); 
                //it prints initialization succeeded but not a1.title
    }
    else {
        printf("Initialization failed\n");
    }
```

Comment: The return type should match the thing you return. You don't return a `int`, you don't return a `int*`, so why did you try these return types? You're returning a `struct book*` so thats what your return type should be...

Comment: `int init_book(struct book *p_book, ...` means your function returns `int`.  `p_book` is a pointer, so what do you expect `return p_book;` to do?  And if you're passing the address of an actual `struct book` to your function, this line means you don't initialize the `struct` that you passed the address of.

Comment: Show us the definition of book.  You probably don't need to malloc space for each field in the book structure.

Comment: `// Single book entry
    struct book {
        char id[10];
        const char *title;
        const char *author;
        struct date release_date;
    };`

Comment: In `struct book`, `title` and `author` are declared as `const char *`. Is that part of the assignment or an idea of yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to return a `struct book *` but you declared the function as returning `int` (or `int *`). This can’t work.

You need to change the return type to `struct book *`. Next, remove the unnecessary `p_book` parameter and convert it into a local variable: It has no use. The result looks like this:

```
struct book *init_book(const char *p_id, const char *p_title, const char * p_author, struct date p_release) {
    struct book *p_book = malloc(sizeof *p_book);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p_book->id[i] = p_id[i];
    }
    p_book->title = malloc(strlen(p_title) + 1);
    p_book->author = malloc(strlen(p_author) + 1);
    strcpy(p_book->title, p_title);
    strcpy(p_book->author, p_author);
    p_book->release_date = p_release;
    return p_book;
}
```

(I’ve also fixed the errors in the string allocation and copying in your code: your code didn’t allocate sufficient space, but the allocation was leaked anyway since you moved pointers instead of copying the contents.)

And it’s called like this:

```
struct book *p_book = init_book("000000009", "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", "J. K. Rowling", a1date);

if (p_book) {
    printf("Initialization succeeded\n");
    printf("%s\n", a1.title); 
} else {
    printf("Initialization failed\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a different approach to the other answers.  I think the return value of your function is intended to be a status rather than the initialized `struct book` since you are passing in a pointer to the `struct book` you wish to initialize.  In that case, you should not be `malloc`ing the book because the pointer you are passing in should already be to a valid memory location of a `struct book`.

Use the return value to indicate whether an error has occurred in initialization.

Without knowing more about your `struct book` it's hard to tell if you need to `malloc` any of the member variables, or just assign pointers.  If you do need to use `malloc`, then you can use the return code from your calls to `malloc` to set your own return value to indicate whether or not there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of a function should match the type of whatever you're trying to return. So to return `p_book`, of type `struct book *`, then your return type should be `struct book *`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks for the catch, I removed that part

Comment: It was specified in the assignment that the function should be of type `int init_book()` so I dont think that would work in the automatic check

Comment: @vNdong then, as others have mentioned, look into passing the `struct book` by reference, then you won't need to return it and could instead return, for example, a success/failure integer